# Is IDENTITY_INSERT session-specific?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is IDENTITY_INSERT session-specific? Say there is an application using table "Test" and is entering some data in it. If i set IDENTITY_INSERT on and insert a row manually, will the application be able to keep on entering rows if it DOES NOT specify any PK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Identity_insert is session specific. The next insert done by an application will use the most recent value as the starting point to calculate the next PK value.

See more at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Not how I read the question but it may be what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. So from what i understand, it is safe to use the IDENTITY_INSERT ON and then insert a row with a specific value as a PK and then use IDENTITY_INSERT OFF. The users will be able to still work in the application, which will do the inserts in the table as usual, even if no PK is specified, since their session is different than mine. Right?

Comment: I just noticed we can only use this with SQL 2008 or high version. Is there a way to do something that looks like this with (i know it's old!) SQL 2000?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of how to do this in SQL Server 2000. Back then it was a pretty raw deal and not very mature. Probably can't do it in that version.

Comment: I will probably speak with my team and lock the table for the time the query runs. Thank you very much for your help on this matter. If anyone has an idea on that, let me know!

Comment: With this information, what does it mean if I do not do `IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`?

Comment: Not the most recent value, but the most recent auto generated value. inserting a PK with IDENTITY_INSERT  ON will not affect the next auto generated identity

Answer (score 1):

I think you confuse what `IDENTITY_INSERT on` means - you must manually specify a value.  You must always specify a value for PK.

Comment: Not if the PK field is marked as 'Identity'. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @bc004346 Understand.  If 'Identity' is active (IDENTITY_INSERT off) then you are specifying a value.

Comment: no, by default (IDENTITY_INSERT off) you are NOT specifying a value for an IDENTITY column. You could specify a value if you set IDENTITY_INSERT ON. Again, straight outta MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx#Anchor_4

Comment: @bc004346 Understand - you are specifying an *automatic* value with IDENTITY_INSERT off .   See my answer.

Comment: No, you are not specifying any value. SQL Server picks up a value for you. You can call it 'automatic' assignment but you can't say that you are 'specifying automatic' value. You are not specifying anything.

Comment: @bc004346 Let it go